# Why doesn't this dollar-sign construct work?

Tags: haskell, dollar-sign

Yep, another dollar-sign question. I'm sorry...
(I used the search function!)

My professor for the course functional programming told us that the dollar sign
'kinda adds an opening parenthese and then a closing one at the end' (it's very roughly described [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2012/09/ten-things-you-should-know-about-haskell-syntax#2--function-call-syntax-is-terse) in more or less the same manner). So

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs $ tail fibs
```

should be equivalent to

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Well, it isn't. The second thing compiles fine, the first thing gives an error:

```
jkjj.hs:1:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a1] -> [a1]' with actual type `[a0]'
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type `[a0]' has none
    In the expression: 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs $ tail fibs
    In an equation for `fibs':
        fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs $ tail fibs

fibonacci.hs:1:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `[a1] -> [a1]'
    In the return type of a call of `zipWith'
    Probable cause: `zipWith' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `zipWith (+) fibs'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `1 : zipWith (+) fibs'
```

And of course, since $ is a function, things like:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 $ zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

won't work, so at the very least the explanation my professor gave was an oversimplification. While writing this post, I tried to place the parentheses so that the error would be the same. I got:

```
fibs = (0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs) $ tail fibs
```

and

fibs = (0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs) (tail fibs)

which both gave me exactly the same error message (except for the column numbers, of course). Why is this? Is a b $ c d equivalent to (a b) (c d) rather than a b (c d)? I think this all has to do with function precedence and/or associativity, but I don't know the specifics. I don't know how you can see what precedence level a function has (except trying a lot of combinations) and I can't find it with google either.

I hope somebody can help me figure this out!

Comment: Well, in the FP article you cite, it reads *A $ is interpreted as: What follows is the last argument to the function you're calling.*, so the question is, what is the function I'm calling? Obviously, the expression left from the $, as you found out.

Comment: True! But zipWith seemed a more obvious choice for 'the function you're calling'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a precedence issue. You have two infix operators here, `:` and `$`. As an infix operator, `:` has higher precedence than `$`, so it binds more tightly. You can ask about precedence in ghci

```
>> :i :
data [] a = ... | a : [a]        -- Defined in `GHC.Types`
infixr 5 :

>> :i $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
infixr 0 $
```

The `infixr` means that the operator groups to the right (so that the expression `a + b + c` is interpreted as `a + (b + c)`)  and the number gives the precedence (higher = more tightly binding).

Also, you need to know that function application has the highest precedence (tighest binding). So in your two expressions, this one

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

is grouped like

```
fibs = 0 : (1 : (zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)))
```

whereas this

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs $ tail fibs
```

is grouped like

```
fibs = (0 : (1 : (zipWith (+) fibs))) $ (tail fibs)
```

which gives you an error, because the expression to the left of `$` should be a function, but in your case it is a list.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `a b $ c d` is equivalent to `(a b) (c d)`. This is because the dollar sign isn't a syntactical construct: it's an infix operator like every other operator, and has to obey the same rules. It's just that `$` applies a function and has *very low precedence* that gives its behavior.

You asked how to find the precedence of an operator. You can use `:info` in GHCi:

```
ghci> :info $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 0 $
```

Note the last line. That says it's a right-associative operator of precedence 0.
(Precedences go from 0 to 9.)

Asking GHCi about `:` gives the following:

```
ghci> :info :
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
infixr 5 :
```

So `:` is also a right-associative operator, but it's of precedence 5. Since `:` has a higher precedence compared to `$`, it'll be grouped into `$`'s left operand.

Comment: Also note that the `:` operator has a precedence of `5`, which seems to be the specific problem that they're having.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Right: you've found out that

```
a b ! c d $ e f % g h
```

can be read as putting parens around the expressions to *both* sides, i.e.

```
(a b ! c d) (e f % g h)
```

This holds true precisely as long as you only use stuff you could define yourself in standard Haskell: functions and infix operators<sup>1</sup>.

Where it doesn't quite work is when you also consider `if`, `case` etc. syntax. In particular, and that's where your professor's explanation becomes rather more useful, *lambdas* are "greedy" to their right:

```
   \x -> f $ a + x
```

means `\x -> f (a + x)`, and not `(\x -> f) (a + x)`. But the "parens to both sides" still makes sense, you just mustn't incorporate the lambda arrow:

```
   \x -> f . g $ a + x
```

means `\x -> (f . g) (a + x)`, and not `\x -> f . g (a + x)`.

---

<sup>1</sup>You could in principle define a custom infix operator with as low precedence as `$`, but that would be confusing.